# EF Core Entity on Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to map entities dynamically in EF Core. So instead of having multiple relationship specified explicitly in the dbcontext I am trying to do it with reflection. So I have this thus far:

```
var props = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
            .Where(p => p.IsForeignKey());

foreach (var prop in props)
{
    var name = prop.Name.Split(new[] { "Id" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];

    var parentTableType = prop.DeclaringEntityType.ClrType
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .Where(f => f.FieldType != typeof(long))
        .First(f => f.Name.Contains(name))
        .FieldType;

    var childTableType = prop.DeclaringEntityType.ClrType
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(long))
        .First(f => f.Name.Contains("Id"))
        .DeclaringType;
}
```

So this is working as I expect it to, I am getting the `Type` of each one of the tables. Now the problem is coming in when I try to actually create the relationship. The `Type`'s of the two tables are obviously variables so I cannot use them as explicit `Type`'s as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<parentTableType>()
    .HasMany<childTableType>();
```

Is there anyway to convert the variables to concrete Types at runtime to allow the above to happen or am I wasting my time trying to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many Fluent API *non generic*  method overloads accepting `string` type name or `Type` type arguments.

Since you have `Type` variables, you could use the corresponding `Entity` and `HasMany` overloads:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(parentTableType)
    .HasMany(childTableType);
```

Comment: The problem I was running into is that even though the foreign key was discovered it would not cascade delete when deleting an entity. So that is why the relationships were manually defined and now are defined using reflection.

Comment: Anyway, the essential part is that EF Core provides a rich set of non generic APIs which almost eliminate the need of reflection as you did in your gist. The above does the same w/o manual reflection.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. Okay that is a much simpler solution than what I did. I can't believe I didn't think of it. Thank you very much Ivan!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm going to remove the first part as irrelevant and leave just the concrete answer